# tuple index based list comparisions in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to compare two large lists of tuples by comparing their specific index values.

```
cu_list = [(1024, '9251', 'b'), (1024, '9254', 'b'), (1024, '9253', 'ad'), (1024, '9231', 'l'), (1024, '9252', 'ad')...]
de_list = [(1024, '9251', 'ad'), (1024, '9254', 'nc'), (1024, '9253', 'l'), (1024, '9231', 'nc'), (1024, '9252', 'nc')...]
```

I need to compare these lists, and form a new list that contains all the elements from cu_list and if comparison is successful then update the values of elements from cu_list.

```
comparison rules:
1- If the second element of tuple in cu_list is found in de_list, then comparison is successful.
2- If the value on 3rd index in tuple of de_list is 'b' then the resultant list must contain the value as 'xb' else it should be the same value as in cu_list.
3- If the value on 3rd index in tuple of de_list is 'l' then the resultant list must contain the value as 'xl' else it should be the same value as in cu_list.

Hence if we follow the comparison rules we may get the following result:
resultant_list = [(1024, '9251', 'b'), (1024, '9254', 'b'), (1024, '9253', 'xl'), (1024, '9231', 'l'), (1024, '9252', 'ad')...]
```

My working:

```
resultant_list = []
for _, prefix, nst in cu_list:
    for d, pre, sst in de_list:
        if prefix == pre:
            if sst in ['b', 'l']:
                nst = 'x'+sst
    resultant_list.append((_, prefix, nst))
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried using nested loops which get my work done but code seems to be so messy. I want to do it in a better way. I hope some built-in functions may help me clean my code.

Comment: So ,post the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which tend to make for terser code. Your call whether it's more elegant.

Deal with finding the matches first. The inner comprehension gets a list of the second elements of `de_list`. The outer one does the comparison:

```
>>> matches = [i for i in cu_list if i[1] in [j[1] for j in de_list]]
```

Now fix those strings:

```
>>> result = [(a, b, 'x'+c) if c in ['b', 'l'] else (a, b, c) for a, b, c in matches]
>>> result
[(1024, '9251', 'xb'),
 (1024, '9254', 'xb'),
 (1024, '9253', 'ad'),
 (1024, '9231', 'xl'),
 (1024, '9252', 'ad')]
```

PS It's conventional only to use `_` for variables you don't use.

Comment: I want the resultant_list to be like: resultant_list = [(1024, '9251', 'b'), (1024, '9254', 'b'), (1024, '9253', 'xl'), (1024, '9231', 'l'), (1024, '9252', 'ad')...] but by you piece of code it would result in all xb and xl. which is the case that if and only if the tuple in de_list has b or l then it should be xb or xl else the same value as in cu_list.

Comment: Hm, right, sorry... that's harder to do with comprehensions. I think your solution might be the clearest thing to do.